# Confusing error message about title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

I just tried asking a good question by providing a title that summarizes my question, but it wouldn't let me. The error says nothing, either. How can I make this work? Just rephrase the title till it mysteriously works?

[image]

Comment: Start by defining what "work" means *within the title*, and you're there.

Comment: OK thanks, I just thought the title should be concise and not too long, but the duplicates also suggest being more elaborate in the title. I'll try that in the future.

Comment: Good to know I could have just added 5 question marks and it would have been accepted.

Comment: Yeah...that's exactly why we don't tell you the trivial way to work around the filter in the error message. We're trying to persuade you to write a *better* title. Longer isn't necessarily better, but generic words like "work" and "problem" don't tell the reader anything when they see these in search results.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll try to write good titles in the future. The error message on the top still doesn't tell me to write a good title, though. Honestly, in the beginning I just thought it was a bug.